# Why are imported private keys stored to addressbook instead to recieving wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, litecoin, private-key, vanity-address, import

I followed [this guide](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/How_to_import_private_keys_v7+) to import private keys which I generated with [vanitygen](https://forum.litecoin.net/index.php?topic=860.0) into litecoin-qt.

```
walletpassphrase yourLongPassphrase 300
importprivkey yourPrivateKeyInWalletImportFormat
```

But now - why are imported private keys stored to *addressbook* instead of local *recieving* addresses in litecoin-qt?

[image: own address in address book?]

That's a bit confusing. Can I recieve payments to that generated addresses now as the addresses where default wallet addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can send coins to this new address.  If you restart your client you'll see the address will have moved to your receive list of addresses.

The new address initially posts in your address book because of the need to scan the blockchain for all transactions associated with that private key.  But you have to actually restart your client to move the address to your receive list of addresses.